# uploading a document on microsoft access from vb.net 2012

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently building a system that allows users to upload or add documents into a database but I do not know which controls to use and coding. Here's my code, I used `OpenFileDialog`:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
            Handles Button1.Click

        OpenFileDialog1.Title = "open a file"
        OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Text file|*.txt"
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

        Dim fileName As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

        Dim fileContent As String = File.ReadAllText(fileName)
        txtattach.Text = fileContent

    End Sub

End Class
```

It opens a save dialog box but it doesn't save to the database. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: This code does not open a `SaveFileDialog`. You're not showing any code where you want to *save* the file.

Comment: Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog
saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save text Files"
saveFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = True
saveFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = True
saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt"            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2     saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
If (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
TextBox1.Text = saveFileDialog1.FileName

Comment: add the code as an edit in your question please.